# C# Como pegar a duração de um MP3 que está em um endereço HTTP

Tags: c#, http

Necessito pegar a informação da duração de MP3 que estão em um servidor HTTP utilizando a linguagem C#.

Já tentei TagLib# e NAudio, sem sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro você dar uma olhada nessa página http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header que trata do header do MP3.

Basicamente, o que você pode fazer é: Se conectar no servidor e baixar o "pedaço" do arquivo que contém o header, fazer uma análise do header, se o bitrate do arquivo **não** for variável, você saberá a duração **exata**, caso não for, você pode *estimar*, porém pra ter certeza, só baixando o arquivo completo e analisando quadro a quadro o arquivo mesmo.